# Knex.js - How To Update a Field With An Expression

Tags: mysql, sql-update, knex.js

How do we get Knex to create the following SQL statement:

```
UPDATE item SET qtyonhand = qtyonhand + 1 WHERE rowid = 8
```

We're currently using the following code:

```
knex('item')
    .transacting(trx)
    .update({qtyonhand: 10})
    .where('rowid', 8)
```

However, in order for our inventory application to work in a multi-user environment we need the qtyonhand value to add or subtract with what's actually in the database at that moment rather than passing a value that may be stale by the time the update statement is executed.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Here are 2 different ways

```
knex('item').increment('qtyonhand').where('rowid',8)
```

or

```
knex('item').update({
  qtyonhand: knex.raw('?? + 1', ['qtyonhand'])
}).where('rowid',8)
```

Comment: hello mikael, i tried .increment, but found the amount to add should be also specified. i.e. .increment('qtyonhand', 1) will do

Comment: Hi @alex ! Knex does not require that second parameter. I wrote a small test to demonstrate it https://runkit.com/embed/zqlhh6jf1jqn However TypeScript typings might force it.

Comment: i believe you @mikael. my comment was not based on knowledge, but on my trial after knex failed for me.