# postgresql, knex, add text to field

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I using the postgresql in node application and knex.

I want to add text to exist field

for example if the field has value "abc" I want to add the "DEF" to "ABC" ==>"abcDEF"

in BASE SQL it is look like that: update  set  = [fieldname] + 'new text'
this is my code that doesn't work

```
var password ={my full object}
password.versions = `[versions]  || ${password.versions}`;
        return  db('passwords')
                .where({
                    id: id,
                    deleted: false,
                    active: true
                })
                .update(password);
```

Comment: FOUND         password.versions =  db.raw(`?? || '${password.versions}'`, ['versions']) ;
FROM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212497/knex-js-how-to-update-a-field-with-an-expression

Answer (score 1):

1. Ok, you are basically are looking for [String concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) operator `||` for this purpose.
2. Any custom select/insert/update logic that is not supported by `knex` can be written using [knex.raw](https://knexjs.org/#Raw). Or event the whole query.

Full example here:

```
const password = {
  // ...rest of the fields
  versions: 'DEF',
};
const update = Object.assign({}, password, {
  versions: knex.raw('versions || ?', password.versions)
})
const builder = knex('passwords')
  .update(update)
  .where({
    id: id,
    deleted: false,
    active: true
  });
console.log(builder.toString()); // => update passwords set versions = versions || ?
```