# How to update a column using other column?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Here is my raw `SQL`:

```sql
UPDATE
  "RESULT"
SET
  result_last_clicks = result_clicks;
```

I can use `knex.raw(sql)` to do this.

How can I do this by using `knex('RESULT').update({result_last_clicks: ??.result_clicks})`

**update**

environments:

`"knex": "^0.15.2"`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is pretty much of a duplicate of e.g. [Knex.js - How To Update a Field With An Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212497/knex-js-how-to-update-a-field-with-an-expression/42262583)

Though with latest knex you can use column reference helper instead of `knex.raw` :

```
knex('RESULT').update({ 
  result_last_clicks: knex.ref('result_clicks') 
})
```