# Create SQL query with knexJS

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I've this sql query:

```
UPDATE events SET quota_over = quota_over / 100 where quota_over >= 100;
```

How can I convert it for knexJS, I have tried with:

```js
knex('events')
    .where('quota_over', '>=', 100)
    .update({quota_over: 'quota_over' / 100})
```

However, the result is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

What you did is dividing "quota_over" string by 100 in JavaScript which would result in `NaN`. To achieve a similar result based on your SQL query, you can use `knex.raw()` to compose a raw SQL expression.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262583/19368995) and this [documentation](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html#raw), you can do something like this:

```js
knex('events')
    .where('quota_over', '>=', 100)
    .update({quota_over: knex.raw('?? / 100', ['quota_over'])})
```

Where ?? is a way to bind column name reference inside `knex.raw()`.

Hope that helps!